# DateTime conversion in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, ssis, type-conversion

DD MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss.sss -> 01 DEC 2012 00:00:34.381

I want the above to be converted from flat file to DateTime in MSSQL using SSIS. What options do I have for this, I keep getting errors when I use the standard DT_DATE?

Comment: what are the errors ? you know how SO works, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about conversion of data types here ("Converting Between Strings and Date/Time Data Types"). It has a chart that shows what format your date needs to be in. Use string functions to make your date match one of these, then convert to the data type you want.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx

Comment: Thanks, solved it by using DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(Row.IDNTIME), "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);